# Using findInterval to assign vector elements to corresponding brackets

Tags: r

The following function receives a vector of positive integers and list of brackets. The function returns a data frame with a logical vector for each bracket indicating whether a given element of a vector falls within that bracket.

## Background

### Received arguments

- Vector `x` consisting of unique positive integers, usually corresponding to:

  ```
  1:6000
  c(1:100, 753:4000)
  ```
- List of `bracket`s, for instance:

  ```
  list(c(1, 325),
       c(1, 651),
       c(1, 976),
       c(1, 1301),
       c(1, 1626),
       c(1, 1952))
  ```

### Behaviour

- For each of the brackets, the function creates a column `int_brakcet_value` consisting of `TRUE` / `FALSE` values indicating whether `i` element of vector falls within the designed bracket

## Function

```
assign_interval <- function(x, brackets) {
    do.call("cbind",
            lapply(
                X = brackets,
                FUN = function(bracket) {
                    findInterval(x = x,
                                 vec = bracket,
                                 rightmost.closed = TRUE)
                }
            )) -> int_dta

    # Create friendly names
    int_nms <- lapply(
        X = brackets,
        FUN = function(brc) {
            paste0("int_", paste0(brc, collapse = "_"))
        }
    )

    # Set friendly names
    int_dta <- setNames(object = as.data.frame(int_dta),
                        nm = unlist(int_nms))

    # Replace findInterval outputs with T/F
    apply(X = int_dta, MARGIN = 2,
          FUN = function(col) {
              ifelse(col == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
    }) -> int_dta

    dta_res <- data.frame(int_dta)
    rownames(dta_res) <- x


    return(dta_res)
}
```

## Tests

```
x <- 1:6505

res <- assign_interval(x = x, brackets = list(c(1, 325),
                                              c(1, 651),
                                              c(1, 976),
                                              c(1, 1301),
                                              c(1, 1626),
                                              c(1, 1952)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is overkill to use `findInterval` when your brackets only have two values (a min and a max). I would suggest this much shorter function based on two `outer` calls with `>=` and `<=`. As you probably know, `outer` is efficient in that it can take advantage of vectorized functions, so here only a single call to `<=` and `>=` will be made:

```
assign_interval2 <- function(x, brackets) {
  stopifnot(all(lengths(brackets) == 2L))
  lower_bounds <- sapply(brackets, head, 1)
  upper_bounds <- sapply(brackets, tail, 1)
  outer(x, lower_bounds, ">=") & outer(x, upper_bounds, "<=")
}
```

The results are the same and benchmarks suggest this is also a bit faster:

```
x <- 1:6505
brackets <- list(c(1,  325), c(1,  651), c(1,  976),
                 c(1, 1301), c(1, 1626), c(1, 1952))

res1 <- assign_interval(x = x, brackets = brackets)
res2 <- assign_interval2(x = x, brackets = brackets)
any(res1 != res2)
# [1] FALSE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  assign_interval(x = x, brackets = brackets),
  assign_interval2(x = x, brackets = brackets)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                                          expr      min        lq      mean
#   assign_interval(x = x, brackets = brackets) 7.851050 11.278404 15.300305
#  assign_interval2(x = x, brackets = brackets) 1.373723  1.628319  3.134719
#     median      uq       max neval
#  13.099052 14.4824 152.33409   100
#   2.192194  3.2971  13.70505   100
```

---

That being said, let's review your code and see if we can make small suggestions to improve your code while staying true to your implementation.

Instead of the `do.call("cbind", lapply(...))`, you could use `sapply`. The `s` in `sapply` is meant to do that exactly that: `s`implify the output by binding the pieces together. It comes at a very small (time) performance cost which should not affect you much here considering you do not have many `brackets`. I also notice that you are using the `->` assignment operator which is not often used by R programmers hence not recommended.

```
dat <- sapply(brackets, findInterval, x = x, rightmost.closed = TRUE)
```

For the friendly names, I think the following would read better:

```
lower_bounds <- sapply(brackets, head, 1)
upper_bounds <- sapply(brackets, tail, 1)
friendly_names <- paste("int", lower_bounds, upper_bounds, sep = "_")
```

Next, a call to `setNames`is a bit inefficient as it copies your data to a separate space in memory. Instead, you should use the `colnames<-` function so it only modifies the attribute of your existing object.

```
colnames(int_dta) <- friendly_names
```

Next, the use of `apply` is pretty inefficient as it loops on the columns. Instead you could just do:

```
int_dta <- int_dta == 1L
```

to convert to a matrix of `TRUE/FALSE`.

At the end, you are again making an unnecessary copy of your data. You can just change the rownames of your current object, then return it.